# cannot able to verify the twitter details in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, twitter

I used this link  **https://dev.twitter.com/apps** I followed the procedure and I got the **consumer key,consumer secret key,access token key,access token secret** details.I put it in my code.I ran in localhost It shows  **twitter.verifyCredentials is not a function.**I enclosed the code can anyone tell me what is the problem in the code.Thanks in advance...

```html
var twitter=require("twitter");
var tweeter = new twitter(
    {
    consumer_key:'xyz',
    consumer_secret:'abx',
    access_token_key:'asd',
    access_token_secret:'www'
});
app.get('/twitterCheck', function (req, res) {
    twitter.verifyCredentials(function (error, data)
    {
        res.send("Hello, " + data.name + ".  I am in your          twitters.");
    });
});
app.listen(8086,function()
{
    console.log("port is listen on 8086");
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is from `node-twitter-api` package. Try using `node-twitter-api`, This will work:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const twitterAPI = require('node-twitter-api');
const twitter = new twitterAPI({
    consumerKey: '*****',
    consumerSecret: '******',
});
const accessToken = "***********";
const accessTokenSecret = "***********";
const params = {};

app.get('/twitterCheck', function (req, res) {
    twitter.verifyCredentials(accessToken, accessTokenSecret, params, function (error, data, response) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            console.log(data["screen_name"]);
        }
    });
});
app.listen(8086, function () {
    console.log("port is listen on 8086");
});
```

Comment: I followed  your code but It shows   { statusCode: 401,
  data: '{"errors":[{"code":32,"message":"Could not authenticate you."}]}' }

Comment: Have you provided you `keys` properly(`consumerKey`, `consumerSecret`, `accessToken`, `accessTokenSecret`). because i tried locally, it returned `user_name`.

Comment: yes sir... i will send the access id with twitter app link

Comment: just I need your mail id.I will send the code with my access id's

Comment: happy to help :)

Comment: I have a doubt JUST SEE THIS LINK: 
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47263815/twitter-stream-is-not-a-function-in-node-js